# Trying to send email (gmail) using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, email, gmail

I'm trying to send an email using PowerShell. For testing purposes, I'm trying to send the email to myself first. I've looked at a couple online references, and here is what I have so far:

```
$from = my@email.com
$to = my@email.com
$subject = "Test"
$body = "Test"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$SMTPPort = "587"

Send-MailMessage -from $from -to $to -Subject $subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credentials (Get-Credential)
```

Once ran, I get the prompt to enter credentials. After entering credentials, I get an error reading:

```
Send-MailMessage : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Credentials'.
```

So I'm led to believe that the error is thrown when I enter in my credentials. When using this feature and the username is the email, am I supposed to type in my entire email, or just the identifier prior to the `"@....com"`? Either way, it doesn't seem to like either and I'm getting an error all the same. Am I using this correctly?

Comment: Try `Credential` (singular) instead of `Credentials` (plural)

Comment: Changing this solved that issue, but created a new issue saying that `Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated`. Trying to figure that out now.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29029364/9902555) should help

Comment: ^This solved it, thank you